# Can't add funds to my Qatari PSN store

Tags: psn

I asked the bank and they said there was no problem with the credit card. The credit card is from Qatar and I use it on the Qatari PSN and still get the `Can't add funds to your  wallet error`. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: i'd recommend instead of adding funds straight to PSN, you purchase a PSN card instead (not sure if you can get to any from Qatar though.)  Amazon also sells them.

Comment: I believe PSN cards are tied to region.  (I know for sure that a US PSN card does not work in the Japanese store.)